# Record high quality audio, amplify it and play it simultaneously in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, audio, aws-amplify

I am a newbie to the android development using Xamarin and C#.
I am trying to record high quality audio, amplify it and then play it back right away.
So far I am able to record and play back using 'AudioRecord' & 'AudioTrack' objects, but no luck with the audio quality and amplification.
Here is the code...

```
private void RecordAndPlayback()
{
    int recordingSampleRate = AudioTrack.GetNativeOutputSampleRate(Stream.Music);
    recordingSampleRate = System.Math.Max(recordingSampleRate, instance.SelectedSamplingRate);
    bufferSize = AudioRecord.GetMinBufferSize(recordingSampleRate, ChannelIn.Stereo, Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit);

    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    audioRecord = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.Mic, recordingSampleRate, ChannelIn.Stereo, Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit, bufferSize);

    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(Stream.Music, recordingSampleRate, ChannelOut.Stereo, Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit, bufferSize, AudioTrackMode.Stream);

    audioTrack.SetPlaybackRate(recordingSampleRate);

    audioRecord.StartRecording();
    audioTrack.Play();

    while (isListening)
    {
        audioRecord.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        audioTrack.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Can someone please guide me in this to record audio with better quality and possibly amplify the audio volume while playing it back?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

At first the audio's quality is just related to the device's hardware , the kbps and the encoding format of the audio file, the sampleRateInHz in the `new AudioRecord`.

So you can try to set a high sampleRateInHz when you create the `AudioRecord` class. In addition, the problem about the high quality audio is a complex problem, you can try to google to learn about the audio's encoding format and the bitrate.

And the code in the sample I found on the internet usually used two bufferSize, one is for the `AudioRecord`, the other for the `AudioTrack`.